# How do I declare an optional parameter in a signature?

Tags: perl, subroutine, optional-parameters, function-signature

Let's say I have

```
use v5.026;
use feature 'signatures';

sub foo ($opt1, $opt2) {
  say $opt1 if $opt2;
}

main::foo(1,2);
main::foo(1);
```

Now I want to call `foo` with and without opt2:

```
foo(1);    # not currently accepted
foo(1,2);  # works fine
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Optional parameters with subroutine signatures require a defined default which is done with `= default_value_expression`. You can hard set this to `undef`:

```
sub foo ($opt1, $opt2 = undef) {
  say $opt1 if $opt2;
}
```

Comment: Cf. [perlsub](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Signatures). In particular, "A positional parameter is made optional by giving a default value". (but there are various other useful information regarding signatures)

Answer (score 3):

You can also allow any number of optional parameters by ending the signature with an array, which will slurp any remaining arguments and also allows no values, like normal array assignment.

```
sub foo ($opt1, @opts) {
```